# Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

While running hive queries like

```
select count(*) from table1;
```

I get the following error in the console.

```
[2018-07-23 21:04:31.749]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild
```

Wondering if anything else needs to be done.

Comment: I've seen the error before when libraries in that specific YARN ResourceManager aren't setup correctly.

Comment: @cricket_007 Can you elaborate it more, I have seen you posting similar problems in SoF, Did downgrading hadoop version work?

Comment: I've not gotten around to fixing this error myself, but I was planning on just reinstalling Hadoop on that node in the cluster. I use HDP 2.5.3, so just using Ambari makes that fairly easy to do